# UItableVIew wrong layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a ViewController with three TableView like the following screenshot:

[image: Page screenshot]

This is the declaration code of three tableview:

```
CGFloat x, y, w, h;

x = 10.0f;
y = 154.0f;
w = 220.0f;
h = 600.0f;

self.usersTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.usersTableView.delegate = self;
self.usersTableView.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.usersTableView];

x = CGRectGetMaxX(self.usersTableView.frame) + 10.0f;

self.groupsTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.groupsTableView.delegate = self;
self.groupsTableView.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.groupsTableView];

x = CGRectGetMaxX(self.groupsTableView.frame) + 10.0f;

self.officesTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.officesTableView.delegate = self;
self.officesTableView.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.officesTableView];
```

The first table has a different content layout. I've try to change the order of the three tables but the first table shows always a wrong layout (I hide the content of the row for privacy).

**EDIT**
Here the data source methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.usersTableView)
    {
        return self.usersDataSource.count;
    }
    else if (tableView == self.groupsTableView)
    {
        return self.groupsDataSource.count;
    }
    else if (tableView == self.officesTableView)
    {
        return self.officesDataSource.count;
    }

    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.usersTableView)
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell_User";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f];
        }

        User * aUser = self.usersDataSource[indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = aUser.Name;

        return cell;
    }
    else if (tableView == self.groupsTableView)
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell_Group";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f];
        }

        Group * aGroup = self.groupsDataSource[indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = aGroup.Name;

        return cell;
    }
    else if (tableView == self.officesTableView)
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell_Office";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f];
        }

        Office * anOffice = self.officesDataSource[indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = anOffice.Name;

        return cell;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you post the code for the data source methods? Is it returning the same number of rows and the same cells for each table view? I tested your code by returning 0 rows and they all look the same for me - so i think the problem may be there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 7 the UIViewController automatically insets the first UIScrollView it can find in the view hierarchy to account for the new translucent UINavigationBar.

To turn of this behavior try to change the 'automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets' property on your UIViewController to 'NO' in the 'init' method.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

More info can be found here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/AppearanceCustomization.html

If that does not help, there must be something wrong with your UITableViewDataSource.